# C# Serialize inherited class without base properties

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a base class with some properties like:

```
public class BaseClass {  
  public string Name { get; set; }  
  public string Comment { get; set; }  
}
```

And classes who extend the base class like:

```
public class A : BaseClass {  
  public string AProperty{ get; set; }  
}
```

and

```
public class B : BaseClass {  
  public string BProperty{ get; set; }  
}
```

Now I need to be able to serialize the data from the extension and from the base class into different Locations.
And for deserialization I need to be able to deserialize one of the classes and "merge" with base class who was deserialized earlier.
The baseclass is mine so I can change it as needet, but not the extension classes (A and B in my sample).
It would be nice to have a solution that works with XML and JSON (Newtonsoft JSON serializer) serializer.
Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by merging the base class.

Comment: When I have an already deserialized object from type BaseClass and need to build for example an object of type A with the BaseClass object and the serialized data located in C:\SerRepo\A.xml

Comment: So you want to construct an object of `A`, copy over the existing properties from your existing `BaseClass` instance, and then deserialize additional properties from json/xml into the new instance of type `A`, not necessarily in that order? And when serializing, you need it to serialize only the additional properties in `A`/`B` because you intend to always do this merging?

Comment: Exactly. I start with an object of type BaseClass. And if needet I need to be able to "expand" to an object of type A/B with the additional data. And for saving I need everithing separated because I need to be able to create objects of type A or B out of the same BaseClass object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be done with Newtonsoft's JSON library with a bit of work by using JObject and Linq to query for properties of the deserialized object and manually doing what you want.

Further info can be found here: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

As an example: If you have a baseObject that has been already deserialized and a string containing the data:

```
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
A aObj = new A();
aObj.Name = baseObject.Name;
aObj.Comment = baseObject.Name;
a.AProperty = (string)jObj[propertyInfo.Name];
```

If you do not know the additional properties of objects, but have access to the types at runtime that can easily be found through reflection. Example continuing from above

```
var t = typeof(A);

PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
foreach (var propertyInfo in pi)
    propertyInfo.SetValue(aObject, (string)jObj["AProperty"]);
```

Comment: Sounds interessting, but I do not know the additional properties an the objects A/B. They are developed outside of my scope (like plugins to my application). And I would like to not have to use Reflection of something like that if not needet.

Comment: @RenéZweifel I have updated my answer to provide an example (I did not have time to test it as I am currently at work) of how you could do it using reflection. Note that it is best to cache results from reflection if you can as it tends to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to do this with XML, but with Newtonsoft JSON.NET:

You cannot merge the deserialized result unless you know the final target type first. This probably means you will have to include the type name in your JSON in some way either automatically via [`TypeNameHandling`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) or manually.

- If you chose to use `TypeNameHandling`, you can create the object by calling [`Deserialize(JsonReader)`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize.htm) and let it create an object of the proper type.
- If you stored the type in some other way, you can create the object by using the overload which takes a type: [`Deserialize(JsonReader, Type)`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize_1.htm)

Once you have the correct object, you can then add the additional properties from the second fragment via [`Populate`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate_1.htm).

---

Note: If you don't know the type of the object until the second fragment, why not just keep the first fragment as JSON and parse the second fragment first? Then add the first fragment via `Populate`. It really doesn't matter in which order the fragments are deserialized as long as they don't have any overlapping fields.

---

To perform the serialization, you will need to use a custom `IContractResolver` to filter the fields. For example, something like this would allow filtering to all properties that are declared in a particular type (Warning: I did not attempt to compile this):

```
public class DeclaredMembersResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> filtered = new List<JsonProperty>();

        foreach (JsonProperty p in base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization))
            if(p.DeclaringType == typeof(T)) 
                filtered.Add(p);

        return filtered;
    }
}

// Example of use:
var ser = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings() {
  ContractResolver = new DeclaredMembersResolver<BaseClass>()
});
ser.Serialize(writer, obj); // Only the base properties of obj will be written
```

Obviously you would then extend the above to do the inverse (exclude base class properties) to serialize your second JSON block.